# Make floating divs move place smoothly when container resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to do something like Apples' iCloud website, where when the screen gets too small the divs slowly move to the new position in an effect.

I'm looking at something like this:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  clear: all;
}
.wrap div {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see when the screen gets smaller the divs move, how do I make them float to the new position in an effect?

I will accept:
- Pure css
- Javascript
- Jquery
and a mix of any as an answer.

I would like to avoid plugins where possible.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried 'transition: all 0.3s ease;' obviously with no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/.

```js
var iso = new Isotope( '.wrap', {
  // options
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: green;
}
.wrap div {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.1/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I definitely looking at a plugin to do this, or is there a simpler way? Also, I need it to be free.

Comment: @AustinCollins What do you mean by simpler? Also, depending on the nature of your project they have an [open source license](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/#open-source-license).

Comment: I mean something that does what I need it to do and nothing else. I don't need the sorting system nor the show/hide system. I've read their licence and I'll have to pay for a developer licence.

Comment: This does work, and although it uses a plugin, I will mark it as the answer for others.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this smooth transition effect with the `transform: translateX(x) TranslateY(y);`

Comment: I have media queries. But I want them to move smoothly when the div is resized.

Comment: so try something like `wrap { transition: all 0.2s; }`

Comment: This would make the wrap resize slowly, not make the inner divs move to their new position slowly.

Comment: try then 
`wrap > div { transition: all 0.2s; }`
This will select immediate children of wrap that are divs and apply the rule to them.  Alternatively you could do `wrap div {transition: all 0.2s; }` to select any descendants that are divs.

Comment: Again, I've tried this. And it does not make any effect.

Comment: Let me look at the iCloud website code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83486/discussion-between-csteele5-and-austin-collins).